# ¿Cómo sumar valores repetidos en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente. Estoy en el desarrollo de una Tabla de Goleadores de Futbol, es una tabla que debe mostrar dos campos: el nombre del jugador y el numero de goles. En PHP programe esto:

```
public function getTablaGolLP() {
    $response = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM resultados_partidos WHERE estado = 'A'");
    //$stmt->bind_param("s", $id_resultado);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $response[] = array(
            'id_partido' => $row["id_partido"],
            'jugadores' => $this->getJugadorByLocalANDVisitante($row["id_resultado"]),
        );
    } return $response;
}

public function getJugadorByLocalANDVisitante($id_resultado) {
    $response = array();
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM resultados_partidos WHERE id_resultado = ? AND estado = 'A'");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_resultado);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       
        $jugadorloc = explode(',', $row['jugadores_local']);
        $arreglo_jugadores = array();

        //array_unique(devuelve todos los valores de un array)
        //count(cuenta todos los elementos de un arreglo u objeto)
        //validar que no se repita el jugador, tanto local como visitante
        //contar el numero de goles segun el numero de veces que se repite el id del jugador y guardarlo en una variable acumuladora
        //in_array — Comprueba si un valor existe en un array
        ///si ya existe el id se suma 1(gol) en una arreglo

        if ($jugadorloc != ""){
            $cantidadgoles = array_count_values($jugadorloc);
            //var_dump ($cantidadgoles);
            //var_dump($jugadorloc);
            $lista_simple = array_values(array_unique($jugadorloc, SORT_REGULAR));
            //var_dump($lista_simple);
            foreach($lista_simple as $key){
                $arreglo_jugadores[] = array(
                    'name_jugador' => $this->getJugadorById2($key),
                    'goles_local' => $cantidadgoles,     
                ); 
                //var_dump($arreglo_jugadores);
            }
        } 
        $response = array(
            'jugadoresloc' => $arreglo_jugadores,
            
        );
        return $response;
    } else return RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
}
```

Este código arma mi respuesta en el servidor. El problema es que no encuentro manera para que los jugadores de futbol que tienen su id no se repitan, puesto hay que los jugadores se dividen en *jugadores_local* y *jugadores_visitante*, en muchos casos se va a repetir el nombre del jugador ya que un jugador en un partido hizo gol de local, y después en otro partido hace algún gol de visitante. Cuando hago el *append* en *JavaScript* me lista todos los jugadores que hacen gol sin importar si es local o visitante.

El otro problema que tengo es que muchas veces esos jugadores van a hacer mas de un gol en el partido, así que no se como filtrarlo para que me aparezca una sola vez. Finalmente en la columna de numero de goles, debo ubicar la veces que ese jugador hizo gol, y la manera de obtener ese valor, es contar el numero de veces que se repite el id del jugador y luego pintarlo en la tabla.

Este es mi código *JavaScript*:

```
$.get('../API/public/tablaGolLP/JugadorByEquipo/', {}, function(returnedData){
    if(returnedData["error"] == false){
        returnedData["tablaGolLP"].forEach(function(tablaGolLP){
            //console.log(tablaGolLP["jugadorLoc"]["jugadores"][0]);
            if(tablaGolLP["jugadores"]["jugadoresloc"][0]["name_jugador"] != 3){
                tablaGolLP["jugadores"]["jugadoresloc"].forEach(function(jugador){
                    temporal = Object.assign([],jugador["name_jugador"]);  ///push
                    repetidos.push(jugador);
                $("#tablaGoleadores").append("<tr><td><center>" + jugador["name_jugador"]["jugador"] 
            + "</center></td>" + "<td><center>" + "</center></td></tr>");
            })
        }
        });
    }else{
        SweetAlert("error", returnedData["msg"]);
    }
}).done($(function(){
    $('#goleadores-data').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        searching: false,
        ordering: true,
        info: false,
        retrieve: true,
        responsive: true,
        order: [[ 1, "desc"]],
        });
    }));
```

A. Cedano, esta es la foto de la tabla de donde extraigo los id de los jugadores que anotaron gol

[image: Estos son los campos, faltaron mas pero los importantes son los id de los jugadores]

esta es la imagen de la respuesta que me da el servidor, me gustaria que el id 5 que pertenece a un jugador x apareciera solo con el name del jugador, y no me imprima el 5 y el 11 que es del otro jugador que anoto gol

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les pido que por favor me ayuden!

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)

Comment: ya lo hice gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Todo depende de cómo hayas organizado las tablas, por favor, explica qué estructura tienen las tablas implicadas en este caso. Si tienes un buen diseño de datos esto se podría hacer con una sola consulta sin demasiadas complicaciones.

Comment: Te comento, solo es una tabla, esta tabla almacena los resultados de cada partido de futbol. En esta tabla hay un campo que almacena los id del jugador del equipo local que anotaron(separados por coma) y los id del jugador del equipo visitante que anotaron gol(separados por coma).

Comment: Como tu indicas, esta tabla es un select o get de datos y pintarlos en funcion al jugador y al numero de goles. Los jugadores que hacen gol se almacenan como un objeto, quiero decir, que se selecciona el jugador que hizo gol y el numero de goles que hizo y se da clic en un boton que los guarda temporalmente hasta que se hayan registrado todos los jugadores. Espero que con esta explicacion pueda entender un poco mejor lo que quiero hacer y puedas darme una mano para terminarlo. Gracias.